# how to add details in two database table in one submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables: `coaches`, `categories` and also a join table `categories_coaches`, on submit I want to store `category_id` and `coach_id` in join table `categories_coaches` and `name`, `email`, `university`, `batch`, `phone` in `coach` table. how to do so?

now details are storing in coach table but not storing in join table

please help me to solve this problem.

coach.rb

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coach
end
```

registrationcontroller.erb

```
class Coaches::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @individual=@individual ||= Coach.new
    super
  end
  def create
    build_resource sign_up_params
    @individual=@individual ||= Coach.new
    super
  end
  private
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:coach).permit(:name, :email, :university, :batch, :linkedin_url, :code, :phone,category_ids: []
     )
  end
end
```

view page
`<%= simple_form_for(@individual, as: :coach, url: registration_path(:coach)) do |f| %>
                  <%= f.input :name, required: true, %>
                <%= f.input :university %>
                 <%= f.input :batch %>
                  <%= f.input :email%>
                 <%= f.input :phone%>
              <div class="category-scroll">

               <% Category.all.each do |c| %>
                <% if c.parent_id != nil %>
                <div class="category-left">
                  <%= check_box_tag "category_ids[]", c.id, false, :id => "category_ids_#{c.id}" %>
                  <%= c.name %>
                </div>
                   <% else %>
                  <b><%= c.name %></b>
                 <% end %>
              <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.button :submit, "SUBMIT", class: "apply-continue_form" %
            <% end %>`

Comment: You say about a join table but you're not using a has and belongs to many of has many through.

Comment: i edited the relation , but details are not storing in join db

Answer (score 0):

What you've mentioned sounds like a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship to me.

I'll detail what you should do, and the underlying mechanics of the association:

---

```
#app/models/coach.rb
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
end
```

This, as opposed to the [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship, does most of the legwork for you. You were correct in setting up your `join_table` as you did:

[image]

The importance of getting this right is that each time you [`CRUD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) either your `Coach` or `Category` objects, you'll have access to their associated data through the `:categories` and `:coaches` methods respectively.

Thus, you'll be able to populate the data like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :coaches #-> url.com/coaches/new

#app/controllers/coaches_controller.rb
class CoachesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @coaches = Coach.all
   end

   def new
      @coach = Coach.new
   end

   def create
      @coach = Coach.new coach_params
   end

   private

   def coach_params
      params.require(:coach).permit(:name, :email, :university, :batch, :phone, :categories)
   end
end
```

This will then allow you to make the following view:

```
#app/views/coaches/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @coach do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.email_field :email %>
   <%= f.text_field :university %>
   <%= f.text_field :batch %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone %>
   <%= f.collection_select :categories, Category.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i updated view code. i cant add association option there. because it is a checkbox option

Comment: Have you tried using my `collection_select` code to see if it works?

Comment: @sree, change the select to collection checkboxes instead then http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Comment: @Rich Peck i tried that code but i want to list categories and subcategories . your code gives checkbox option for all categories and subcategories  . i need checkbox only to sub categories option. so that here needs a condition

Comment: @japed if please can you edit my code. i am not getting what you have mentioned

Comment: Your original question is about *populating the join table*. My answer is designed to achieve that. All this extra stuff about sub categories and checkboxes is for another question. If my code works to populate your join table, you should accept it and invite us to answer another question.